# How do I compile all files in a directory with mono?

Tags: c#, mono

I want to compile a C# app with mono that consists of multiple files (all in 1 directory).  What is the command that I need?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
gmcs -out:yourapp.exe -pkg:dotnet *.cs
```

or

```
gmcs -out:yourapp.exe -pkg:dotnet35 *.cs
```

Those commands will reference all the assemblies referenced by default in .NET.

Answer (score 3):

gmcs -target:exe -out:program.exe *.cs

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only thing you need is the output file.

```
gmcs -out:bob.exe *.cs
```